# Copy text on handheld via tap in wearos

Tags: android, clipboard, wear-os

I am trying to build an authenticator sort of android app with support for WearOS , what i want to accomplish is ->
from a list of TOTPs if the user taps on any one of them ON THE WEAROS app , i want the OTP to be copied on my android handheld ( even when the authenticator application is closed)

is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to communicate from your Wear App to your paired Mobile app using the Message Client.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService

Your authenticator mobile app will be woken up when the wear app sends a message, and then handle it as you want.

See here for more information about data syncing. https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data/data-layer

Comment: so.... click on mobile = opens mobile app , where i copy the data to clipboard & then close the app ?

Wouldn't that look weird ?

Comment: I don't think you need to visibly launch the app, you should get notified of the message and handle it however you need.  I don't think what you are trying to do is already supported, so you are likely to have to write some code on both wear and mobile to make this happen.

Comment: I'll look into that ! thanksss